# Is this possible in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to return only those who match *all* the list values in `LINQ`?

I have one table `klist` in which two columns are available:

```
Kid  -  Tableid  
001      1
001      2
002      1
003      3
004      1
004      2
```

and I have a list that contains `tid` value:

```
List<int> tid = new List<int>();
tid.Add(1);
tid.Add(2);
```

now the `tid` list have 1 and 2 value.

So my question is that from `klist` table I will only get those `kid` which contain all the `tid` list values and compare with table id.

The expected result after this is

```
kid - 001
kid - 004
```

I tried the query below:

```
var lb = Klist.Where(t => tid .Contains(t.Tableid)).Select(k => k.Kid).Distinct().ToList();
```

**But that returns all the matching kid, if even single match then they give that result, but I want only those who match all the table id with tid list.**
And result of my query is

```
kid - 001
kid - 002
kid - 003
kid - 004
```

Please suggest a `LINQ` query for this.

Comment: Is LINQ must? I can give solution with sql query.

Comment: No i want this in LINQ

Comment: Maybe this [intersect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7565274/1257607) answer can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you first need to `Group` your values by `Kid`:

```
Klist.GroupBy(k => k.Kid)
```

The result is a list of distinct `Kid`s with their corresponding `Tableid`s.

After that, we need to select the groups for which all their `Tableid`s are the same as the `tid`s. This can be achieved by removing the identical elements from both lists, with `Except`. We then check if there's no remaining elements (i.e. both sets are equal).

```
.Where(g => tid.Except(g.Select(s => s.Tableid)).Count() == 0)
```

Finally, get the `Kid` of the remaining groups, which is stored as the `Key` in the group:

```
.Select(g => g.Key);
```

If we assemble everything together, we get the following LINQ query:

```
var lb = Klist.GroupBy(k => k.Kid).Where(g => tid.Except(g.Select(s => s.Tableid)).Count() == 0).Select(g => g.Key);
```

returning the elements `001` and `004`

Answer (score 1):

You can group `kList` first,then use `SequenceEqual` with `tid`,here is a demo

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> kList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("001",1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("001",2),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("002",1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("003",3),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("004",1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("004",2)
};
List<int> tid = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
var query = kList.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
    .Where(g => g.Select(j => j.Value).Distinct().OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(tid))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => x.Key)).Distinct();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", query));
```

and maybe `SequenceEqual` has some problem,if you want `contains` all `tid`,not `Equal`,then you can use `Intersect` to instand of `SequenceEqual`,the code is like this

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> kList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("001",1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("001",2),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("002",1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("001",3),//special one
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("003",3),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("004",1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("004",2)
};
List<int> tid = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
var query = kList.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
    .Where(g => g.Select(j => j.Value).Distinct().Intersect(tid).Count()==tid.Count)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => x.Key)).Distinct();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", query));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fairly nicely:

```
var kList = new []
{
    new { Kid = "001", Tableid = 1 },
    new { Kid = "001", Tableid = 2 },
    new { Kid = "002", Tableid = 1 },
    new { Kid = "003", Tableid = 3 },
    new { Kid = "004", Tableid = 1 },
    new { Kid = "004", Tableid = 2 },
};

var tid = new List<int>() { 1, 2, };

var lookup = kList.ToLookup(k => k.Tableid, k => k.Kid);
```

This produces:

```
1 => "001", "002", "004"
2 => "001", "004"
3 => "003"

var result = tid.Select(t => lookup[t]).Aggregate((ts0, ts1) => ts0.Intersect(ts1));
```

The `tid.Select(...)` produces `{ { "001", "002", "004" }, { "001", "004" } }` and the `Aggregate` then performs the intersect on these two.

The result is:

```
001 
004
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it:

```
var list = kList.GroupBy(x => x.Kid)
            .Select(group => new 
             { 
                 Kid = group.FirstOrDefault().Kid, 
                 gtid = group.Select(groupItem => groupItem.Tableid).ToList() 
             })
            .Where(group => !group.gtid.Except(tid).Any() 
                 && !tid.Except(group.gtid).Any())
            .Select(group => group.Kid);
```

Basically like the other solutions, you group the data in `kList` and create a new list with the `kid` and a list of `Tableid`'s. And then filter that new list by comparing the list of `Tableid`'s to your `tid` (making sure one has no list item that is not in the other and vice versa). Then out of that, you select the `kid` values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers that `Except(Func<T, bool>).Any()` or `Except(Func<T, bool>).Count() == 0` but both of these combinations seem like they should just be `All(Func<T, bool>)`.

Based on your question you say you want only the `kid` value when it exists in `All` rows for that `kid` value. This is how I would do it.

```
var lb = klist.GroupBy(lst => lst.Kid)
              .Where(t => tid.All(td => t.Select(x => x.TableId).Contains(td)))
              .Select(grp => grp.Key);
```

This groups the table into sets that contain the `Kid`. It then filters out the rows where not `all` of the tid values exist. It then selects the key for those groups which is the `Kid`.